Hiding whole network behind Reverse Proxy
I'm creating a newtork of Ubuntu virtual machines, all on one ProxMox server.
My concept is to have one or two (initally just one) front-end reverse proxy.
Its job, in theory, is to accept all traffic on the ports that are open to the internet and change the port to an internal only port and where the traffic is encrypted to decrypt that traffic. All traffic within the system is unencrypted. As part of this front-end VM is a lite version of postfix and dovecot to act as the client login for mail and as the SMTP sending server for client mail as well as the mail relay for the internal mail servers.
Mail arriving on port 25 that is unencrypted is to be trapped and sent to a quarantine mail box on the front-end VM.
HTTP traffic to be redirected to HTTPS, but once again all HTTPS traffic that passes through the reverse proxy to be unencrypted within the system and to be on an internal only port.
My problem is the reverse proxy.
I have tried several options just on the mail traffic for now, but I'm having no end of trouble trying to separating unencrypted port 25 traffic and then unencrypting all other traffic before passing to postfix for authentication and either passing on accepted mail or processing the originally unencrypted port25 traffic.
The system will have other VM's using other protocols at a leter stage: eg SIP, Streaming audio.
So my question(s) is:
Am I trying to do something that is outside the skope of a reverse proxy?
If it is a reverse proxy function which open source application would be best suited.
If outside a reverse proxy function what other options would be recommended to achieve the desired outcome.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
